# Unable to use the Literal attribute in an F# Signature file (.fsi)

Tags: f#

I'm unable to define a literal in an F# signature file.

I have a file, `File.fs`, as below:

```
module Thingo =
  [<Literal>]
  let hello = "world"
```

I need to create a signature file for it, so initially tried this (`File.fsi`):

```
module Thingo =
  [<Literal>]
  val hello : string
```

This caused the following error in `File.fsi`: `A declaration may only be the [<Literal>] attribute if a constant value is also given, e.g. 'val x : int = 1'`

I gave that a go:

```
module Thingo =
  [<Literal>]
  val hello : string = "world"
```

The line *after* the `val hello` declaration received the error: `Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in signature file. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.`

So it doesn't like me assigning values in a signature file (or I don't know how to assign the value, very much a possibility).

The docs say that I *do* need to assign the value in the signature somehow:

> If the `Literal` attribute is used, it must appear in both the signature and the implementation, and the same literal value must be used for both.

(from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/signatures)

I also auto-generated a signature file (with the `--sig` build argument) and it spat out:

```
module EventSchema = begin
    [<LiteralAttribute ()>]
        val id : string
end
```

I tried this exact syntax, but it didn't work either.

Thanks for reading! Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your third snippet (the one which includes the string value) works if you remove the ``=`` after the module name. But then it fails if you add other lines, it seems that it only works if the literal is the last thing you declare, which seems to be a bug.

Comment: Assuming this is a bug, has this been fixed in some successive release of F# since this question was asked a year ago, or is it slated to be fixed in an imminent release?  I've run into the same problem.

Comment: Sadly, I never solved this, but I have also not kept up on trying to fix it. I have no idea if it's going to be fixed in a future release.

Comment: It has been fixed now and will be part of the next release of F#, see https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer should have been: it's a bug. It was reported here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7897.

Note that, as a workaround, you can switch light syntax off, then it will work in current versions.

Note also that the compiler will error when the constant values don't match with the one in the signature file.

Answer (score -2):

You should either use namespace at start of file just before module or remove "=" sign. Also, type annotation is not required. F# is pretty good at type inferrence.

```
module Thingo
  [<Literal>]
  val hello= "world"
```

or

```
namespace My.App.Modules

module Thingo =
  [<Literal>]
  val hello = "world"
```